# Freeglut on Fedora 26 and codeblocks

Tags: fedora, c++, opengl

I have fedora 26, I have latest codeblocks and freeglut and freeglut-devel.

In codeblocks wizard I pick glut project. It asks me to enter a location but it can't detect it. I tried `/usr` and `/usr/include` and `usr/include/GL`. How to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member on [codeblocks forums called Jens](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,22175.new.html) solved my problem

Create a global variable `Settings -> Global variables` with the name `glut` and enter `/usr` in `base` and `/usr/lib64` in `lib`

And keep the default `$(#glut)` as location in the wizard.

[image]